# auto-generation of python file info(author, create date etc.)

Tags: python, pydev

I'm using pydev in eclipse. When new a .py file, there will be file info(author, create date etc.)generated like below:

"""
Created on Fri Oct 10 13:50:18 2014

@author: XXXX
"""

How to change the format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Window-Preferences-PyDev-Editor-Templates-Change your Empty template

Comment: thank you! and I also referred http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246192/how-to-change-the-value-of-user-variable-used-in-eclipse-templates to change variables.