# Change @author name in AnyLogic

Tags: eclipse, anylogic

When I create classes in AnyLogic, which is based on Eclipse, the `@author` tag automatically takes the name of the account I'm using, e.g., `Work`. I would like to use a custom name, e.g., `John Smith`. How do I do this?

Comment: I strongly suspect you can't do this. As you've seen with your other questions, there are plenty of 'generated Java internals' which AnyLogic doesn't expose. Whether they **should** all be 'exposable' is a more explosive question :-) Perhaps you can work round it if there is any way of 'overriding' the `System` `"user.name"` setting, which is what I presume AnyLogic is calling to populate the `@author` tag.

Comment: Any idea where I might find that in Windows? I know how to set it when Java is launched from a `cmd` window, but not when AnyLogic launches :S

Comment: No, sorry. How do you do it for a cmd-line launch out of interest?

Comment: Sorry, it can be done when [Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246192/how-to-change-the-value-of-user-variable-used-in-eclipse-templates?rq=1) is run from a command window.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure: this does work with functions within AnyLogic as in the attached screens. Never tried to comment classes but I don't see why it wouldn't work the same way...!

[description section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqc0R.png)
[auto complete result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dw7sS.png)