# Append author onto JavaDoc Headers in existing files upon saving Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, javadoc

I want to automatically append my user tag to the class documentation when I edit an existing class from the following:

```
/**
 *
 *
 * @author inoue.orihime 
 *
 */
@Entity
@Table
public class ..
```

To this:

```
/**
 *
 * @author inoue.orihime 
 * @author ichigo.kurosaki 
 *
 */
@Entity
@Table
public class ..
```

Is this possible on eclipse or using some 3rd library ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the value of ${user} variable used in Eclipse templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246192/how-to-change-the-value-of-user-variable-used-in-eclipse-templates)

Comment: @eFox How is this question is duplicated, I already did my search before I asked, the question you are referring to is to how change the value of ${user} which is not my question, The file where I want to add `@author ${user}` is already created by someone else, I just want to add my name too when I edit the file and save it.

Comment: As far as I gather it you're asking how to edit the template for the header code to insert your own new variable, the answer is the same thing. If your question differs, you need to be more clear about what you're actually asking.

Comment: @eFox I think I was clear about my question, I said `Whenever I modify some existing file on eclipse` and not `when I create a new file on eclipse` and I gave an example where a file is already created by the author `inoue.orihime` and then I said when I edit this file I want `to add the @author automatically to an existing @author` so the file then will have two `@author` names and not just one for the user who initially created the file and the user who modify the file, like in MS Word you always have the initial author and persons who contributes in the file.

Comment: If you think you were clear, let me help you edit your question

Answer (score 0):

The Javadoc for a class is defined as a *Code Template* in `Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Code Templates`. In this preference page, select `Comments => Types`, then you will see the default Javadoc for new classes/interfaces/enums/annotations. Click on the `Edit` button to change its content.

[image]

Comment: This only works for `new classes/interfaces/enums/annotations` and not existing files, as I said the file is already created by someone else, I just want to add my name too when I edit this file, so this option should be when I save the file.